# Predict system failure

Tags: linux, windows

Is there a way to predict failure of a server by measuring system parameters like CPU usage, memory usage etc ?

The failure can be because of different reasons.

My question was worded poorly. Hence this edit

**EDIT**

Can we use some sort of machine learning from the data collected(system parameters) to predict if the server is going to go down ?

We would've logs of conditions of the server when it was active as well as when it failed

Comment: Seems that someone has given you a "-1", try to be more precise in your request. What do you want to monitor, what OS, how many, etc. Many tools exist in order to monitor such parameters but it depends of what you really need.

Comment: To first approach any such prediction, you must first understand what it means for your system to fail. Then if you determine that, you might then put your effort into monitoring and alerting for that, and you might be able to use some autoimmunity sort of technique to try and rectify the situation. It is worth noting that answering this question will also improve your signal-to-noise ratio for your alerts.

Comment: From what I read the OP is not as much asking for the failure indicators of a ***server*** (although he has worded it this way) but of a ***service***. This is where monitoring CPU and memory usage make sense as overload conditions often would lead to prolonged service times and a perceived outage.

Comment: Question edited

Comment: The question is not just poorly worded, it's a poor question for this site: 'Don't ask about ... Questions with too many possible answers or that would require an extremely long answer'  And you don't seem to have a specific problem to solve, you're just asking airy generalities, which isn't encouraged here.  You also haven't shown research effort, understanding, knowledge, attempts to do what you want etc, etc

Answer (score 2):

Buy yourself a server and components that test themselves periodically and report back on 'pre-failure' warnings. It's the ability for servers to do this that really sets out the difference between the top players (HP, IBM, Dell) and lesser makes - it costs more of course but for some it's worth it.

For instance the HP DL380 Gen9 server has literally hundreds of sensors around the unit and its components which combine to provide these 'pre-failure' warnings when possible. This really does routinely work and their support contracts, again not cheap, allow for hardware to be swapped based on this information - you can swap out a disk/controller/memory/CPU/PSU etc. *BEFORE* it's failure impacts you.

So to summarise, if availability is key to you then buy servers that can do this and configure them to report this information as it happens.

Answer (score 1):

No, at the very least not in any general way, as different systems are so vastly different in about every aspect you might check.  As an example, on my web servers I would be worried if they reach 100% CPU for more than a very short time, but on the compute nodes, not having 100% CPU usage might be an indication for concern.

You could try to install some monitoring system (e.g. Nagios/Icinga) and come up with threshold parameters that make sense in your specific use case, but you have to think long and hard about what parameters to check and what thresholds to set for your specific circumstances.